# The Launcher doesn't appear nor the Manager apps and settings

Tags: unity

I have only the window options at the desktop. I'm able to open the firefox through the option `get help online`, but if I minimize the window I cannot acceed it anymore. So I cannot access to the programs or anything else. Do I have to reinstall ubuntu (I have the 11.10 version) or is there another option (for a beginner in linux).

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a screen shot here? Press the PrntScreen key on the top right of your corner to take a screen shot. Or use a camera.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> and type

```
unity --reset
```

This will take a minute or two to set your Unity back to defaults and restart itself.

If you've got applications open you may still be able to switch to them and maximise with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: It worked. I have the launcher and all the rest. Thanks a lot for the help